# is there a method to create a text field and color words in text in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, web

i created a django project :
so in my page html , i have a list of words colorated with different background colors :

```
hello (colored in red) 
world  (colored in yellow)
```

i do this with :

```
<span class="token-label" style="background-color=red">hello</span>
```

in the same page , i want to display the text which contains the two words , but i want to colors the words in the text according to colors of each word:

```
 hello, i'am here ! hello world !    with "hello" colored with red and "world" in yellow
```

Comment: Actually, if you want to color only two words you can wrap them in the span tag
<span>hello</span> <span>world</span>

Answer (score 1):

I can't write a full idea of mine I think you can write it by yourself and here a quick example of what I wanted to create, it's not perfect because of its hardcoded regexp expression in .replace() method but I hope you will understand what I wanted to achieve

I would do it with regexp because I can have something like hello, (as in your example) or !world! and if you want to trigger those words you have to use regexp I hope so. You probably want to separete ! from "world" !
It will be something like

```
<span>!<span><span class="world">world<span><span>!</span>


CODE:

<p class="text">
  hello, i'am here ! hello world ! 
</p>


.hello {
  background-color: red;
}


let text = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerHTML;

let text_split = text.split(' ')
let new_arr = []
for(let i = 0; i < text_split.length; i++) {
    new_arr.push(`<span class="${text_split[i].replace(',', 
'')}">${text_split[i]}</span>`)
}

document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].innerHTML = new_arr.join(' ');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tj67q1zd/